# How can I reuse part of components in father router and change some component in children router?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

About the App.vue:

```
<template>
  <el-container class="home-container">
    <el-header>
      <Header/>
    </el-header>
    <el-container style="height: 100%"> 
      <el-aside width="250px">
        <router-view name="menu"></router-view>
      </el-aside>
      <el-main>
        <router-view name="main"></router-view>
      </el-main>
    </el-container>
  </el-container>
</template>
```

And about the router:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import CompareView from '../views/CompareView.vue'
import LabToolsMenu from '../components/LabTools/LabToolsMenu.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    components:{
      menu: LabToolsMenu,
      main: HomeView
    } 
  },
  {
    path: '/LabTools',
    components:{
      menu: LabToolsMenu,
      main: HomeView
    },
    children:[
      {
        path: 'Sensor/Search',
        components:{
          menu: LabToolsMenu, 
          main: CompareView
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'Sensor/Compare',
        components:{
          menu: LabToolsMenu, 
          main: CompareView
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

I want to update the main component when changing the path,
for example, when path is '/LabTools'， the page uses the component of '/LabTools' and when path is '/LabTools/Sensor/Search', the components update to component of '/LabTools/Sensor/Search', but it did not work

So, how can I implement such function?
In addition, how can I use the same component of father and just update the children components when changing paths?

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know your intention why you display/structure the components in this way but the following example works. I hope my approach will help to clearify your problem.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="home-container">
    <div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/labtools">Labtools</router-link>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/labtools/search">Search</router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/labtools/compare">Compare</router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**router.ts**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "./views/HomeView.vue";
import Content from "./components/Content.vue";
import LabToolsMenu from "./components/LabToolsMenu.vue";

export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: HomeView,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          components: {
            menu: LabToolsMenu,
            main: Content,
          },
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/labtools',
      component: HomeView,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          components: {
            menu: LabToolsMenu,
            main: Content,
          },
        },
        {
          path: ':id',
          components: {
            menu: LabToolsMenu,
            main: Content,
          },
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
});
```

Comment: Emmm, I am a rookie in Vue and I just want to load different components in different part of the App.vue, and how will the menu and main components display in App.vue without setting name='menu' and name = 'main' and just use one router-view?

Comment: I have found the solution for my problem, thank you for your response

Comment: @蔡王辉 Maybe you can share your solution how you´ve solved?